# Angular Material md-button not working

Tags: html, css, angular-material

I have created a  html page and used angular material for responsiveness but when i try to add a button using md-button it does not work but md-card is working fine.

I have included all the files shown below

> Blockquote

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Image preview App</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    </head>
    <body ng-app>
    <md-card style="width:50%;height:300px;">
     <md-button>button</md-button>
    </md-card>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not seeing it because it does not get highlighted, apply a style

```
 <md-card style="width:50%;height:300px;">
        <md-button class="md-raised next-btn">button</md-button>
 </md-card>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/4Cy5Bk2EEFvlYnMfJ7i9?p=preview)**

Comment: I did that it does not work. And i dont want to create any functionality in controller for button. I just want to include built in classes and it should work.Am i missing any files that needs to be included in head .

Comment: Check the demo attached. It has all the references

Comment: I got it. I checked your demo and found out. It was not working because i did not create a module and injected ngMaterial to it, once i did that it started working. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your background is white and your button color is white. Try changing the color of one or the other.

```js
<md-button style="color: #662D91;">button</md-button>
```